# Packaging Desktop App and UWP App together, should I remove the package.appxmanifest file from the UWP project?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, desktop-application, packaging

I'm packaging a UWP App and a regular Desktop App together. When I deploy the Windows Application Packaging Project, it seems to install both the UWP app alone and the packaged version so I end up with two versions of app installed. So is it safe to remove the package.appxmanifest file from the UWP project?

EDIT:

So it isn't possible to remove the package.appxmanifest file.
However, is it possible to prevent my UWP app from building twice when I click Deploy on the packaging project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So is it safe to remove the package.appxmanifest file from the UWP project?

I'm afraid you can't remove package.appxmanifest file from the UWP project, it will throw exception for uwp side. Every app package must include one package manifest.

```
Project must have either AppxManifest item or Content item with name 'AppxManifest.xml'.    UWPCore
```

For more detail please refer to [App package manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appx-package-manifest) document.

Comment: I see, is there a way to prevent the UWP App from deploying itself separately then when I click deploy on the packaging project?

Comment: UWP app's maifest file will not effect, it will process the capabilities base on pakcage project's manifest file.

Comment: Yeah I figured that part out, but I don't get why I end up with the UWP app packaged on it's own in addition to the packaged project version that includes both the UWP app and Desktop app when I click deploy from the packaging project.

Comment: it's secure for system that packaged  as uwp app could make your app run in the sandbox,  and it could meet the requiriment of store publishing.